# Как отключить автоматическое сохранение снимка с камеры в галерею

Tags: java, android

Из активити вызываю приложение Камера, указав место, где сохранить снимок. Получаю снимок, обрабатываю, использую и удаляю из того места, куда сохранил. Но он остается в Gallery в папке Camera.

Как его удалить или сделать так, чтобы он там не появлялся вообще? Перебрал методы настройки камеры - не нашел такого метода. В опциях Intent-a камеры тоже не нашел.

Comment: Вот вам линк на enSO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390163/deleting-a-gallery-image-after-camera-intent-photo-taken
Надеюсь, это то, что вам нужно

Comment: Спасибо. Буду разбираться и отвечать.

Answer (score 1):

Вобщем реализовал так.
Перед запуском интента камеры, запоминаю текущее время в милисекундах в глобальной переменной

CurrTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

Затем в onActivityResult перебираю все файлы в галерее и удаляю те, у которых lastModified() >= CurrTime.
Потом обновляю галерею.

```
Cursor cursor;
            int columnIndex;
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, // Which columns to return
                    null,       // Return all rows
                    null,
                    null);
            columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToPosition(0);
            do {
                String imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                File F = new File(imagePath);
                if(F.lastModified() >= CurrTime){
                    F.delete();
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()}, null, null);
```